# Wait until element has disappeared in Cypress

Tags: cypress

please, tell me what `methods` to use to wait for a loading screen element to disappear? PS. I'm not using an `API request`.

I tried to use two `methods`, but it doesn't work properly:

**1.** `cy.get('#loading', { timeout: 30000 }).should('not.be.visible');`

I get the error: `-- Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: #loading, but never found it.`

**2.** Used plugin (cypress-wait-until) like so `cy.waitUntil(() => {document.querySelector('#loading') === null};`

This approach doesn't find the element at all.

Comment: solved, it works for me -  cy.get('#loading', { timeout: 40000 }).should('not.exist');

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to retrieve an element that is not in the DOM, use `not.exist` instead:

```
cy.get('#loading').should('not.exist');
```

In cases where you do need to wait, you can try using `cy.wait`:
An example use case for this might be if Cypress has to route to your page first and you want to ensure the page loads before you start testing:

```
 cy.wait(200);
```